# Adding --no-check-certificate to wget in Jmeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, wget

I am using Jmeter to hit an https url which is behind firewall and i am using a proxy.

When I am using wget, I get thhis error:

```
--2014-12-12 16:14:49--  https://xxx.company.com/
Resolving proxy.net... xx.xx.xx.xx
Connecting to proxy.net|xx.xx.xx.xx|:80... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name "yyy.company.COM" doesn't match requested host name "xxx.company.com".
To connect to xxx.company.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.
```

After using the `--no-check-certificate` option `wget` is working fine.

But when I'm running `wget` through Jmeter,I am getting connection timed out error. Can anybody help me, how can i use `--no-check-certificate` option in Jmeter.

I am using Jmeter 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter does not validate certificates so your issue is not what you think it is.

If wget works on the same machine where you get the timeout in JMeter, check that JMeter uses the same proxy configuration:

See this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Answer (score 0):

echo "check_certificate = off" >> ~/.wgetrc